# elfinder configuration

Tags: php, redirect, ckeditor, file-manager

I have a problem with Elfinder configuration.
All standard ways doesn't work and also this configuration:

> 'root'            => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/elfinder/',
>
> 'URL'             => 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/images/elfinder/',

seems not to work. I get Invalid redirect error.
I don't have acces to apache error.log / system console - only FTP access.

Is there any way I can debug elfinder / find what cause redirection?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need is to check that JSON output from connector is valid, you can make it using FireBug extension, if there are some PHP warnings than client will not be able to parse response.

Also try to set `'root' => './'` for debugging purpose.

Comment: I was using Firebug@FF
The problem were caused by server custom software - zip checking was sending header even with @

Comment: This is know bug and it depends on server and PHP configuration, elFinder2 will not be affected by this bug.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after remove url and include path like this:

'path' => $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/images/elfinder/',